# Post nested object from Android retrofit2, Server receive sub-element null

Tags: java, android, post, retrofit2, nested-object

Using Retrofit2 to post a nested object towards server (SpringFramework). The first level attributes can be read by Server, but null for the List attributes.

Checked that the Sub-element (List) has set object before post through Retrofit2 on Android App.

### Android Side (Retrofit2 Call Server API):

```
@POST("rest/upload")
@Headers("Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8")
Call<UploadResponse> uploadRecords(@Body UploadRequest uploadRequest);
```

### Android Side (UploadRequest Object):

```
public class UploadRequest extends AbsRestRequest {
    @Expose
    List<FlatenAttributesObject> ListOfFlatenAttributesObject;

    public List<FlatenAttributesObject> getListOfFlatenAttributesObject() {
        return ListOfFlatenAttributesObject;
    }
    public void setListOfFlatenAttributesObject(List<FlatenAttributesObject> listOfFlatenAttributesObject) {
        ListOfFlatenAttributesObject = listOfFlatenAttributesObject;
    }
}
```

### Java Server Side Code (UploadRequest object):

```
public class UploadRequest extends AbsRestRequest {
    private ArrayList<FlatenAttributesObject> ListOfFlatenAttributesObject;
}
```

### Java Server Side Code (Controller):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<UploadResponse> Upload(@RequestBody UploadRequest requestObject) {
    UploadResponse response = new UploadResponse();

    System.out.println("\t" + requestObject.getActionType() + " \t" + AdmsUtils.date2Str(requestObject.getActionDateTime(), DateFormatConfig.getWebDateTime())); 
    //String attribute in AbsRestRequest can be read. 

    System.out.println("\tRecord Count of FlatenAttributesObject: " + (requestObject.getListOfFlatenAttributesObject()==null?0:requestObject.getListOfFlatenAttributesObject().size()));
    //Null object for requestObject.getListOfFlatenAttributesObject()

    ......
    return new ResponseEntity<UploadResponse>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

> Why the requestObject.getListOfFlatenAttributesObject() read as null on Server? It is checked that the object has been set in Android App before post.
>   (Checked on Android Studio debug mode)

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed.
Root cause is on the server side coding.
The attribute in Class UploadRequest, the first letter of the variable should be in lower case.

```
public class UploadRequest extends AbsRestRequest {
    @Expose
    List<FlatenAttributesObject> **l**istOfFlatenAttributesObject;

    public List<FlatenAttributesObject> getListOfFlatenAttributesObject() {
        return **l**istOfFlatenAttributesObject;
    }
    public void setListOfFlatenAttributesObject(List<FlatenAttributesObject> listOfFlatenAttributesObject) {
        listOfFlatenAttributesObject = listOfFlatenAttributesObject;
    }
}
```

The first letter of "**L**istOfFlatenAttributesObject" causes springframework cannot recognize the attributes.
it should be "**l**istOfFlatenAttributesObject" and the problem has been fixed.